# How to solve word problems of polynomial asking to find dimensions of blocks given the follwing?

Tags: polynomials

The question is 
A monument consists of two cubical blocks of granite, the smaller resting on the larger. The total height of the monument is 5 feet, and the area of the exposed surface is 61 square feet. Find the dimensions of the blocks.

The thing i got is that the area of the exposed surface is 61 square feet and the height of the monument is 5 feet. I can't seem to understand what is says about exposed surface. How would i solve it i mean the first block of the two would have 4 sides right and the other would be? I don't know how to proceed from here? can anyone help me set up the whole thing or just explain how i could do this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the length of a side of the top cube and let $b$ be the length of a side of the bottom cube.  Then you know that $a + b = 5$.  Now, think about these questions:

1. What's the area of a single face of the top cube?  How many of those faces are exposed?
2. What's the area of a single face of the bottom cube?  How many of those faces are completely exposed?
3. What's the area of the exposed part of the top face, i.e. the part that isn't covered by the top cube?

If you add up the expressions from (1), (2) and (3), you'll have the total exposed surface which the problem says has to equal 61.  That gives you an equation that has both $a$'s and $b$'s in it.  If you solve the original $a + b = 5$ equation for either $a$ or $b$ and substitute that into the other equation, you'll have a quadratic equation that has one variable in it which you can solve to get the solution.